# MySQL, selecionando 4 tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um select em 4 tabelas diferentes. Todas estão relacionadas. Tudo começa com o **ID_Morador**.

```
SELECT morador.*
      ,unidades.*
      ,grupo.*
      ,condominios.*

  FROM morador
  LEFT JOIN unidades
    ON id_morador = morador.id_unidades,
  LEFT JOIN grupo
    ON id_grupo = morador.id_grupo,
  LEFT JOIN condominios
    ON id_condominios = morador.id_condominio

 WHERE morador.id_morador = '1';
```

**Teste online:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537518/5

Comment: FRON não, FROM...

Comment: e tem um monte de vírgula a mais.

Comment: @Bacco Editei, mesmo assim tem erros. É a primeira vez que uso o ``LEFT JOIN``. Você faria a gentileza de editar no link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537518/5 e informar a forma correta que funcione? Posta o link editado aqui.

Comment: é só tirar as virgulas depois dos JOIN, e depois de condominios.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudei o SQL, a principio eu não vi a falha nos `jois`, você está tentando fazer `left join` de tudo com a tabela `morador`. Eu acho que o corretor seria o SQL abaixo, mudar o nome dos alias para o que vai melhor lhe atender.

```
    SELECT 
    m.*, a.*, b.*, c.*

FROM morador m

LEFT JOIN unidades      a   ON m.id_unidade       = a.id_unidades
LEFT JOIN grupo         b   ON a.ID_Grupo         = b.id_grupo
LEFT JOIN condominios   c   ON b.id_condominio   = c.ID_Condominios

WHERE
    m.ID_Morador = '1';
```

Fiz um teste no seu Fiddle com esse SQL e ele rodou.

Para usar o alias nas colunas você não pode usar o `*` terá que listar todas as colunas, o que também é o mais indicado.

```
SELECT 
    a.nome as uniNome, b.nome as grupNome
```

O fiddle não está funcionando assim, mas é dessa forma que se fazer, olha esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341178/3517631) onde existe uma resposta igual para a sua dúvida do comentário.

Comment: Estranho, agora esta falando que não achou a tabela ``unidades`` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537518/14

Comment: Desculpa, comentei a resposta. Tem que mudar o `Select` tb

Comment: ``Unknown column 'a.ID_Morador' in 'on clause'`` o que seria isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta agora, releia, refiz ela toda. Acho que agora chega onde você quer.

Comment: Ricardo, você é o cara! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ricardo, você pode me ajudar com mais um detalhe? Existe algumas tabelas que o campo tem o mesmo nome, preciso criar um alias, como fazer? ``unidades.nome AS unNome ``, ``morador.nome AS moNome``, ``grupo.nome AS grNome``

Comment: Você diz no `Select`, certo? Para ficar com nome das colunas corretos?

Comment: Ricardo, sim exatamente

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Tudo certo, obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 4):

Acho que tem alguns erros de sintaxe, tenta essa.

```
SELECT 
    morador.*, unidades.*, grupo.*, condominios.*

FROM morador

LEFT JOIN unidades      ON ID_Morador       = morador.id_unidades
LEFT JOIN grupo         ON ID_Grupo         = morador.id_grupo
LEFT JOIN condominios   ON ID_Condominios   = morador.id_condominio

WHERE
    morador.ID_Morador = '1';
```

Comment: Bom, é basicamente o que eu pus nos comentários, não?

Comment: Vish eu não vi os comentários cara, desculpa... Fui direto na pergunta.

Comment: Não tou reclamando não, só queria confirmar se era aquilo, ou se achou mais algum erro. Eu tava tentando arrumar o fiddle dele, mas o SQL Fiddle tá impossível de usar hoje.

Comment: Eu tentei no fiddle também mas não rolou, ta dificil mesmo, ai eu fui olhando e vendo com o que eu via de cabeça, me parece correto assim. Mas não consegui rodar o teste :/

Comment: Basicamente tinha um FRON (que ele editou na pergunta depois), e as vírgulas a mais no select e nos JOIN.

Comment: Estou testando agora diretamente no MySQL, esta parecendo esse erro ``#1052 - Column 'ID_Grupo' in on clause is ambiguous``. O que seria?

Comment: Bota alias em todas as tabelas, é uma coisa boa para se usar sempre. Evita futuros ambiguous também.

Comment: @Ricardo Você pode postar como deve ficar?

Comment: Os joins estão errados, seria bom arrumar para não confundir.

Comment: Seria bacana você não trazer tudo de todas, mas escolher os campos.